# Bug on link rendering only in view mode (not in edit)

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

Please see: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6233875/7373716

There is a bug on the last character of the answer, the last bracket is not rendered as a link, and so the link is erroned, as you see in my screenshot below.
Note that the bug isn't present in edit mode, weird.
[image]

Comment: No [red freehand circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/158100)? And there is some black smudge  on your screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Fixed.  The markdown is cached so it didn't pick up the changes like the editor.  Making a little edit forced it to update and the link works now.